# Unable to add values with objects to table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

```
$('#tbreceipts tr:last').after('<tr><td>data3[i].amount</td></tr>');
```

I have tried to add values to table cells using this code within a for loop while adding rows to table.

This code doesn't seem to be working, why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're trying to load in a variable to a string.

Close the string, use the add operator `+`, add the variable and then add the rest of the string on.

```
$('#tbreceipts tr:last').after('<tr><td>'+data3[i].amount+'</td></tr>');
```